# Nice rsync on remote machine

Tags: ssh, rsync

When using rsync+ssh to access a remote machine, is there a way to "nice" the rsync process on the remote machine (to lower its priority)?

Editing the question to clarify:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
backups  16651 86.2  0.1   3576  1636 ?        Rs   11:06   0:06 rsync --ser...
```

(rsync line snipped)

This is a backup cron job that normally runs at 4am, but when I happen to be awake (and committing, or using Bugzilla hosted on that same machine), it kills server performance, so I wanted a quick "hack" to try and fix it a bit.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `--rsync-path` option, eg.

```
rsync --rsync-path="nice rsync" foo remotebox:/tmp/
```

Comment: You might consider using [ionice](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/ionice.1.html) as well, e.g. `--rsync-path="ionice -c 3 nice rsync"`, though modern Linuxes automatically reduce the IO priority for nice'd processes (see the man page I linked).

Comment: I already tried that, but my sshd is still running at `nice 0`

Comment: on FreeBSD like systems where you don't have `ionice`, setting the `--bwlimit` option is good for a nicer rsync.

Comment: I also had a problem with this option not making any difference. It turned out that the server I was connecting to was configured in authorized_keys to only accept a specific rsync command, which was overriding the ```--rsync-path``` option I was specifying.

Answer (score 13):

- Taking the **`--rsync-path` option** you have `rsync --rsync-path="ionice -c 3 nice -n 12 rsync" localDirectory remoteHost:/tmp/`
- Taking the **configuration file option** you can change or uncomment in file `/etc/default/rsync` the `RSYNC_NICE='17'` value and the `RSYNC_IONICE='-c3'` value

For both the **ionice** value will be for hard disc priority

- 1 -> Real time
- 2 -> Best effort
- 3 -> Ildle (when any other process is not using the HD)

Note that for Linux only `cfq` scheduler really implements IO classes and priorities. If the remote system administrator has opted to IO scheduler `noop`, `deadline` or some more exotic variant you may find that `ionice` really does nothing. One should be able to get high performance from `cfq` and still be able to use IO classes and priorities by [tuning cfq correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41831/20336).

for **nice** value for processor priority

- -20 (most favorable to the process)
- (default 10) if -n is not specified
- 19 (least favorable to the process)

Comment: Who is responsible for `/etc/default/rsync`? Is rsync itself reading this file, or is this done by the linux-flavor/distribution?

Comment: ... I think I found the solution `/etc/default/rsync` is the defaults file for rsync daemon mode. I guess it only applies if you connect to the rsync daemon via rsync-protocol. I guess it does not apply if you call it via ssh.

Answer (score 4):

You could disable the compression along the network, by not including the `-z` argument, that might save some CPU time on either side. Or change how rsync uses checksums, look at `--checksum`

Comment: I accepted Hasturkun's answer (since it answered my question), but you brought up a good point: I benchmarked with compression vs without compression, and it only added 2 minutes to the job. I just got so used to using -avz as my flags that I never thought of dropping -z.

Comment: My habit is to use -aPh, I rarely use -z

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty solution would be to create a small wrapper script called 'rsync' that shadows the $PATH before real rsync binary like:

```
#!/bin/sh
nice -10 /path/to/proper/rsync $*
```

Or setup the authorized_keys file so that it performs nicing of rsync. (Assuming you are using ssh keys).

example:

```
command=”/home/user/bin/nice-rsync.sh" ssh-dss asdf....
```

Now in your /home/user/bin/nice-rsync.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
case $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in
  rsync\ --server*)
    nice -10 $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
    ;;
  *)
    $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
    ;;
esac
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Rsync should not be using much CPU. I doubt that you can force a certain niceness from the other end, but what you could do is limit the bandwidth that rsync is using with a firewall, which would ultimately reduce how much processing it could do in X amount of time.

Comment: Added some output from 'ps aux' to show what it is doing as far as CPU. I'm going over a slow link, so I have the --compress option turned on, but it is also causing a good amount of disk access, which I was hoping to knock down by using nice (unintended side effect)

Comment: Setting a nice value usually also affects the I/O niceness, which is  what someone usually wants.

Comment: `rsync` does not require much CPU but it might show up in `top` nevertheless depending if the current kernel considers I/O wait as busy. In addition, if any other process needs to access the storage and `rsync` is allowed to run at full pace all the other processes will be slowed down as a result.