# Rsync when system resource utilization is low

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I have a machine that suffers periods of resource contention (CPU or Memory or Disk or some combination) and I don't want Rsync to add to the problem when that occurs. Is it possible to setup Rsync to that it "slows dow" or stops during periods of contention (effectively being lazy)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the resource, but you can do the following:

- CPU: set the `nice` level of the process to a high value (lower it's
  priority)
- Disk: set the `ionice` level of the process to an idle
  scheduling class
- Network: use `tc` to set the network TOS or use the `--bwlimit` arguement
- Memory: Interesting one - there's some complex methods using systemd or
  cgroups.

See this thread for more details: [Nice rsync on remote machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/55560/nice-rsync-on-remote-machine)